# xslt duda when (apply-templates)

Tags: xpath, xslt

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase y me falta un detalle. Tengo que sacar un listado de autores de un libro.
Mi idea es que si tiene varios autores ponga una coma entre ellos y si tiene solo uno que salga solo el autor.

/*Aquí estaría todo el XML, pero solo pongo lo que "interesa"*/

```
<autores>
 <autor>Autor 1</autor>
 <autor>Autor 2</autor>
 <autor>Autor 3</autor>
 <autor>Autor 4</autor>
</autores>
```

/*Parte del xsl que "interesa"*/

```
    <xsl:template match="autores">
    <div class="celda">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="autor and following-sibling::autor">
        <xsl:value-of select="autor"/> 
        <span>, </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="autor"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>    
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

La idea que tengo es que cuando le preceda un nodo llamado autor ponga un span con una coma y espacio,
y cuando solo tenga un nodo autor que represente ese texto sin coma.

Llevo tiempo con ello y he probado más opciones aunque me parece la más sencilla.
Si necesitáis todo el código puedo adjuntarlo pero es un poco largo ya que tengo otros
nodos dentro de autor pero no quiero liarlo mucho.

El resultado que obtengo:

```
Autor 1Autor 2Autor 3Autor 4
```

Gracias por la ayuda, saludos.

Añado el código donde se ejecuta.

```
<xsl:template match="autores">
    <div class="celda">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="autor and following-sibling::autor">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="autor"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="', '"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="autor"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

Es un apply-template.
Hay 137 líneas de código, si necesitáis el código completo hacérmelo saber por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por como estás aplicando la transformación, la validación va al aplicar el template de `autor`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



<xsl:template match="autores">
    <div class="celda">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="autor"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="autor">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="local-name(./following-sibling::*) = 'autor'">
        <xsl:value-of select="', '" />
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

El siguiente nodo *hermano* se ve desde el nodo autor, no desde la plantilla del padre.

Otra forma es usar las funciones de posición para identificar el último nodo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



<xsl:template match="autores">
    <div class="celda">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="autor"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="autor">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="', '" />
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Esto lo probé con XPath 1.0. Con 2.0 seguro hay más poder en las expresiones y demás.

Comment: Sí pensé en simplicarlo como dices, no conozco mucho el lenguaje y esta es la solución a la que he llegado, pero no se como hacer para insertar texto. He probado las dos opciones y no me han servido, ahora he probado también poner "&#160; " en vez de <xsl:value-of select="', '"/> en el último ejemplo.
¿Puede que la version afecte?

Comment: @77hector77 versión de qué? Creo que necesitas incluir al menos los encabezados del xsl para ver bien qué pasa

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

Comment: Recuerda que el código y las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta ;)

Comment: Sí gracias, por intentar no liarlo mucho lo he liado más. Puedo poner todo el código, pero son casi 140 líneas y no se hasta que punto sería liarlo aún más. Perdona, y gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Es que no es que sea todo, pero ni siquiera vemos cómo haces el foreach, nada. No nos das mucho para probar

Comment: He añadido el código, es un apply-templates por lo que creo que no es necesario for-each.

Comment: @77hector77 respuesta editada

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, he probado la segunda opción y me sale. Algo parecido estuve probando pero no logré unir todos los cables, no caí en que podía haber puesto el last(). Muchas gracias, tengo mucho que practicar y aprender.

<xsl:when test="position() != last()">
     <xsl:value-of select="', '" />
 </xsl:when>